# Trying to connect to https through terminal

Tags: linux, curl, https, terminal

i can connect to it throw my browser, i mean i type host than it asks me for username and pass i type it and i am in.. but.. i cant connect to it via terminal using curl.

```
$ curl -v https://.../... -3 --basic -u uname:upass -A Mozilla/5.0
* About to connect() to ... (#0)
*   Trying ...
* connected
* Connected to ...
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: nofile
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ....
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=...
*    start date: 201
*    expire date: 201
*    subjectAltName: ... matched
*    issuer: C=U
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'uname'
> GET /pls/hun/tlh.lt_reg HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic thisoneisgood=
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> Host: ...
> Accept: */*
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host ... left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Try `--anyauth` instead of `--basic`. Do you have access to server's access logs?

Comment: did't helped, no i don't have access to logs. i even tried to set the same headers as in browser. i get headers with Live HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem  was with curl, the new version of curl works only with sslv3 server was working on sslv2, so i had to get older version of curl recompile it and write -2 instead of -3. note that if you write -2 with this curl version you get same error... curl doesn't writes that it does not support sslv2 you have to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the version of your cURL by `curl -V`, 7.24.0 is having the same issue while 7.35.0 is working fine.